# Fatal Signal 11 0x97614008 (code=2)

Tags: android, fatal-error

I have found many threads about the fatal signal crash on Android and all are due to various reasons. So here is my stack trace:

```
04-02 16:58:20.263: E/OpenGLRenderer(4633): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-02 16:58:20.263: E/OpenGLRenderer(4633): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-02 16:58:28.475: A/libc(4633): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x97614008 (code=2), thread 4633 (droid.APPNAME)
04-02 16:58:29.603: E/OpenGLRenderer(4704): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-02 16:58:29.603: E/OpenGLRenderer(4704): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
```

Can anyone read useful information out of this?

Comment: Either there's a bug in the OpenGL implementation shipped on your device (it has happened in the past), or your program is asking it to do something unreasonable.  A more complete stack trace, and a minimal test program which triggers it, would be helpful.

Comment: This is the complete stack trace I'm afraid. My application is using the google maps sdk v2 and the crashes appear randomly.

Comment: No, that is not the complete stack trace.  Actually, it's not a **stack trace** at all.